# ActiveAdmin Rails doesn't display entries for model named "Ads"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I've got a few entries in a model named Ad.
When accessing the model's URL **/admin/ads** , I can't see the table rows because they are being given a CSS id similar to **"ad_1"**. Inspecting the source shows that the id has the rule **display:none** in an Active Admin style-sheet. Can I implement any workarounds?

Comment: What does your resource register look like? Is the model called `Ad` or `Ads`?

Comment: I have edited my post, the name of the model has a singular form - Ad

Comment: I haven't changed the register, it's the default one `ActiveAdmin.register Ad do
  
end`

Comment: where does the `display:none` come from? i don't think that ActiveAdmin does this on purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for your help, unfortunately it's something silly. Adblock Plus adds display:none to #ad_1, #ad_2 and so forth. Disabling the extension fixes this issue.